# Decompiling Delphi .dcu to .pas

Tags: delphi, syntax-error, decompiling

I'm running RAD Studio Delphi XE2. Something strange appears to have been done to one of my .pas files. Many of the lines from my unit1.pas have been replaced with simply 'º' and others are missing. I am left with a small section of code from somewhere in the middle of my original file. Can I get the original unit1.pas back by somehow decompiling unit1.dcu?

Also, why would this happen? Have you heard of this before? The code runs but, obviously, I can't edit anything I can't see.

Comment: Just check out a fresh copy from your version control repository, or restore from backup. (It's hard to say what might have happened, because you've quoted a single character and say "others are missing".) You're never going to get the "original unit1.pas" by decompiling, because the variable names and other info simply aren't in the .dcu file. You might be able to get some salvageable logic, but it's not going to be 'unit1.pas'.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I got a old version from the history tab fortunately I'd not done too much to it. I was using a file on a network location, I don't know if that could cause this but I'll be using a local copy from now on.

Comment: You really should get a real VCS. Subversion, Mercurial, or Git are all free, pretty easy to configure and use (some even with GUIs or Windows Explorer extensions to be even easier), and XE comes with support for SVN built in. It can really save your backside. :-) The IDE's _history is not a real version control system, and it stores only the last 10 copies by default (although you can increase that number).

Comment: Actually (just edited - sorry) I'm using XE2 - but I guess it's the same. :-) I've looked into a couple of Gits. I'll pay more serious attention to them now.

Comment: Try opening the .pas file in another (text) editor, just in case it's a display issue, and another computer, just in case it's a problem with that computer.

Comment: Seriously. Learn to use Mercurial.  http://hginit.com

Comment: Possible causes: Running out of disk space (or quota since you mention it's a network share). Network error when saving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you could decompile it, it would likely be an unmaintainable mess compared to your original.

Instead, try looking in the `__History` folder for your project. You should find older versions of your code. Pick the newest one ;-)

> why would this happen?

Any number of reasons. Bug in the IDE? Bug in an IDE plugin or a custom component? Bug in *your* code that overwrites a source file, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for this. I doubt there's anything in my code that could cause this. Could it be to do with access a network based file, rather than a local copy?

Comment: A network share? Maybe one of your cow-orkers enjoying a joke...? I'd keep sources locally, and push them to network-based revision control.  Delphi's `__history` folder is useful for this short-term stuff, but often I find I've dug myself into a big coding hole and need to back out all the way to the start of the day. `__history` won't usually help there.

Comment: I doubt it - they're personal files held on the network so I can access them anytime. It's a mystery. I'll working locally and push/pulling from now on.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decompile a .dcu file to the original source. Information is lost in the translation from source code to executable code. Type declarations, variable names, method names, code layout and so on are simply not present in the compiler's output. Compilation is a one way process.

If you use revision control, you'll just be able to pull the latest version from the repository. If you don't use revision control, you've just learnt a lesson the hard way and you will never again attempt to perform software development without revision control.

Comment: Thanks for this. Fortunately I had a recent version that I reverted to that was just a few lines of code different. ;-)

Comment: @Trojanian I have a little saying, "If you aren't using revision control, you aren't doing software development".

Comment: Actually, .dcu files contain quite a lot of info compared to the linked binary. Function names and type info is definitely there. Maybe even local variable names.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: have a look [at this](http://hmelnov.icc.ru/DCU/readme.txt), for example.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky You are claiming that you can reconstitute the original source from a .dcu file? I'm claiming that you cannot.

Comment: I did not claim that. I just said that not all of the information is lost, and quite a lot of it can be recovered.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I did not say that all of it was lost. Perhaps you can show me how to recover local variable names. Or show me how to recover the original source. The questions asks how to recover the original source. My answer starts: *You cannot decompile a .dcu file to the original source.* I think you are getting confused about what question was actually asked. I agree that not all the information is lost. I never said otherwise. Since the question wants to recover it all, what use is your observation?

Comment: "Type declarations, variable names, method names, code layout and so on are simply not present in the compiler's output." <- this part of your answer is not completely correct, and that's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky In what sense is it not correct? Note that I did not say that **all** type declarations are not present. Or that **all** method names are not present. Please try to understand this in the context of the question that was asked, not the subject of decompiling that is your personal interest. Remember that the goal here is to reconstruct the original source. As I said, *You cannot decompile a .dcu file to the original source.*.